# How to pass dynamic file parameter in curl command in shell script

Tags: shell

**for file in split_*
do
curl -F 'institutionId=4010' -F 'file=@$file' -F 'userName=testUser' -F 'userRole=admin' -F 'checkerId=R18502' -F 'product=CDL' http://localhost:8080/gonogo/scheme/upload/scheme-status-authorization
done;**

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2qJt.png)

I have tried multiple options:-
'file=@${file}'
'file=$file'
but nothing is working.

please help me out.

Comment: Use double quotes. `"file=@$file"`

Comment: it is not working this way. thanks

Comment: Use `set -x` to enable trace logging, and compare the curl commands shown in that trace before and after. With the single quotes, you'll see it never passes the filename to curl at all. "Not working" can mean a lot of different things -- I'd suggest turning up the verbosity until you can see the actual request that curl is making. If that request includes your file's contents, the specific problem this question focuses on is solved.